# when i click on ion-icon method in ion-card is also triggered

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a `ion-card` when clicked it's open the card on another page and I have one function on `ion-icon` that is placed above `ion-card` which is when clicked it opens the profile page.

The problem is that when I click the `ion-icon` it triggers `viewProfile()` method and it also triggers `openPage()` method in `ion-card`.

```
<ion-card class="cards" text-left (click)="openPage(item)"
      *ngIf="uid != item.uid && !item.hasOwnProperty('opponentUid')">
  <!--Card-image-->
  <div card-image>
      <img [src]="item.imageUrl" />
      <span edit text-uppercase>
         <ion-icon name="contact" (click)="viewProfile(item.uid)"></ion-icon>
      </span>
   </div>
</ion-card>
```

Any suggestion how to solve this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As *ion-icon* is contained within *ion-card*, I  would suggest moving the ion-card click action on the card-image div.

```
<ion-card class="cards" text-left 
      *ngIf="uid != item.uid && !item.hasOwnProperty('opponentUid')">
  <!--Card-image-->
  <div card-image (click)="openPage(item)">
      <img [src]="item.imageUrl" />
      <span edit text-uppercase>
         <ion-icon name="contact" (click)="viewProfile(item.uid)"></ion-icon>
      </span>
   </div>
</ion-card>
```

Comment: I moved the `ion-card` method in `img` and it worked. Thanks

Comment: Great! Please don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you.